# Add Bytes at beginning of a binary file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a hex string which I converted to bytes like this:

```
string hexString = @"504b0304140000000000";

File.WriteAllBytes("0.bin", StringToByteArray(hexString));

//        
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
{
return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
.Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
.Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
.ToArray();
 }
```

Now I need to add "**0.bin**" or **StringToByteArray(hexString)** to the beginning of an existing binary file "**1.bin**"

I have tried to append **1.bin** to **0.bin** but the bytes are added to end of 1.bin instead of the beginning.

```
    byte[] bytes = StringToByteArray(hexString);

    using (var stream = new FileStream("1.bin", FileMode.Append))
    {
        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
```

> Recap: I need To combine bytes of 0.bin + 1.bin in this order into one binary file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using a temporary file. Write 0.bin first, then 1.bin into it. Delete 1.bin and rename your temp file to 1.bin.

Comment: `File.WriteAllBytes("tmp.bin", File.ReadAllBytes("0.bin"));
File.WriteAllBytes("tmp.bin", File.ReadAllBytes("1.bin"));` You mean like that? Because I tried but It just replaces it. Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: What replaces what?

Comment: 1.bin replaces 0.bin

Comment: Thank you PepitoSh! I figure it out using OpenRead and OpenWrite filestream.